# Highcharts export with html2canvas - graph are out of borders

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, html2canvas

I'm trying to export with html2canvas and getting a weird behavior:

```
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#"+this.data.targetElement)).then(canvas => {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });
```

[image: hi]

but when I'm trying just to copy web element by ID all fine:

```
    var cln = node.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(cln);
```

I will be appreciated for any help.

Comment: Hi @Sergiy Matvienko, Could you reporduce that problem in some online code editor? In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4811/ everything works as expected.

Comment: @ppotaczek The thing is that I can't reproduce it in jsfiddle or any other, I see this issue only on my production. I was hoping maybe someone had the same or similar problem and can share a solution.

Comment: Ok, if you will be able to reproduce the issue, please provide me a demo.